# XNA Vector2 ambiguous issue with Farseer library

Tags: c#, vector, xna, ambiguous, farseer

So I searched and couldn't find anyone else having this problem:

When I try to use a Vector2 anywhere in my code, the following error is spit out at me:

Ambiguous reference:
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2
match

Yes, both libraries are identical. It seems like I have referenced this twice or something... I have no idea what the problem is. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample snippet of one place where this is happening:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace Super_Pong.Engine.World
{
    public class GameWorld
    {
        Vector2 v1 = new Vector2(1, 2); //Error line
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your references. Are you referencing 2 versions of XNA?

Comment: Ok so after compiling it here is the error I'm getting:

Comment: C:\Users\Anthony\C#\Super Pong\Super Pong\Super Pong\Engine\SuperPongGame.cs(31,29): error CS0433: The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll' and 'c:\Users\Anthony\C#\Farseer\Branches\Class\bin\Debug\FarseerPhysics.dll'

Comment: Check that the FarseerPhysics project targets XNA v4 as well.

Comment: How do I do this? Under references?

Comment: Ok, I see the issue. The Farseer Physics project contains Microsoft.Xna.Framework as a reference, which contains Vector2. I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Farseer allows the use of the library outside of an XNA project. Therefore there are multiple versions of the library. The version not depending on XNA recreates these types internally. You need to reference a differetn version of the farseer library, namely the one built for XNA.

You can download it from: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/64108